# SELECT statement for each Where clause

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, duplicates, where-clause

I want to get an individual result set from the Select statement for the WHERE clause that has the same condition. Obviously there maybe different conditions too. This query is a part of a program so it has to give me exactly what I need. For e.g.

```
SELECT * from MyTable 
WHERE 
  x = 'DISPMSG' OR  x = 'DISPMSG' OR x = 'DISPMSG' OR x = 'DISPMSG' 
OR x = 'DISPMSG' OR x = 'RSSET';
```

What this query brings me is 2 result set obviously. But what I want is that it should give me the **same result** set in an array of the size of 5 and 1 with the different condition because there are 5 + 1 conditions on a where clause. I know that the query needs to be looped or something but can't figure out the right way to do it.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: SO is a great site to [ask GOOD questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious! To help us help you, generate sample data and expected results. [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes the output easy to read! You could also mock up data and the SQL tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.

Comment: I think you want 6 records in the record set 5 being dispmsg and 1 being rsset.  but a where clause FILTERs data.  So if you don't have 5+1 records the SQL will not create it.  Now.... you could CROSS Join to a table of 5 records and somehow count 5 for dispmsg and 1 for rsset duplicating records; but why?  This type of action is better handled in the UI not data retrieval.   Why would you want more data to go over a network when its repetitious? both sending the data, and retrieving the records when you could get a smaller data set and repeat the data in the UI as needed?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know it is a stupid question and maybe I did not explain it right. I am using it on a sqlite database. I was thinking there may be a way to get the records for each where clause. now I know there is no way and have to use union all. But it still works faster than working on UI. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to use the "union all" operator, your query would become :

```
SELECT * from MyTable WHERE x = 'DISPMSG'
union all
SELECT * from MyTable WHERE x = 'DISPMSG'
union all
SELECT * from MyTable WHERE x = 'DISPMSG'
union all
SELECT * from MyTable WHERE x = 'DISPMSG'
union all 
SELECT * from MyTable WHERE x = 'RSSET';
```

Comment: What happens if there are two records that are DISPMSG.  Is the OP asking for 10 records of DISPMSG then?

Comment: Thank you.. your solution worked. Up voted but the vote cannot be seen.

Comment: If the op wanted 10 records, there would be 10 union all. The op wants, we abide.  @DhBh could you mark the answer as accepted please ? and you cannot see the vote because "someone" downvoted it.